# Is there a better way to work with the success page (success.phtml) in Magento?

Tags: magento

I'm attempting to do a number of things with the success page (order confirmation page) in Magento but I am faced with the nuisance of having to create a test order every time I wish to see a change because hitting refresh redirects you. The style changes are easy as I can fresh only the CSS if necessary but some of the conversion analytics (e.g. Google) and other items I'm trying to include on the final page aren't as straight forward. Is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento clears session information for a customer after they place their order as it assumes most users will leave the site after that. It’s more of a user-experience feature than it is a security feature. That being the way it is, when you hit refresh on the order confirmation page, your information will disappear and Magento will generally tell you “you have no items in your cart.”

You can disable this for the purpose of development by going to app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php and commenting out the line that says:

$session->clear();

Should be line 240. Change it to //$session->clear(); and Magento will instead allow the session to expire naturally according to how long session life is set to for that specific instance. Now you can style success.phtml or see what conversion information is being sent to various service providers (PepperJam, Google, Proclivity, etc..) without having to create more than 1 test order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium, Firefox Add-on to record a macro for placing an order. This should avoid the repetitive process of placing an order.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-expert-selenium-ide/

You can also use this bookmarklet to auto-populate the fields on the checkout page.
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/auto-populate-magento-checkout-bookmarklet/

Comment: Thank you Srikanth, I will give that a shot as well.